# Xamarin forms push notifications from App Center - no messages getting through

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, push

I am trying to get push notifications working from a sample app.  Whenever I send a message from App Center, I get 0/0 messages sent and I don't see anything happening in my app.

I followed the instructions at http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/push/xamarin-android. At the same time I implemented App Center Analytics. That seems to work since I can send TrackEvent messages and see them in App Center.  I am building my app on VS Mac.

I set up the Firebase Cloud Messaging and got the Android API Key
I added the Nuget packages.
I didn't need to update the AndroidManifest.xml file.
I didn't do anything about ProGuard since I don't use it (or know what it is)
I didn't do anything about the OnNewIntent stuff - it's not clear how to tell if that's needed or how/where to do it.

In MainActivity.c I have the AppCenter.Start(..., typeof(Push), typeof(Anayltics), typeof(Crash));
In my App.xaml.cs I have

```
 public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (!AppCenter.Configured)
            {
                Push.PushNotificationReceived += (Sender, e) =>
                {
                    string summary = "Title=" + e.Title + " Msg=" + e.Message;
                    Console.WriteLine(summary);
                };
            }
            AppCenter.Start("androidkey" + "ios=ioskey;", typeof(Push), typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));          
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyPage());
        }
```

In my MyPage.xaml.cs I have

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            Push.PushNotificationReceived += (Sender, e) =>
            {
                string summary = "Title=" + e.Title + " Msg=" + e.Message;
                Console.WriteLine(summary);
            };
```

I have put the google-servicesjson file in the main folder of the Android app and set its build action to GoogleServicesJson.  I had to do that by manually editing the csproj file.

I put breakpoints at both console.write... statements and then never get triggered.  Like I say, I send off a message from App Center and it never arrives.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks
Les